# getting sound on .asf video on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, quicktime, windows-media-player, asf

When I try to open the following video:

http://streaming1.hss-win.rpi.edu/ondemand/cogsci/issues_in_cs/issues_in_cogsci_02_04_2009.asf

I can get it but without any sound... I tried it both inside the browser (Firefox) and in QuickTime Media player but still it does not work. Any idea how to get this to work on Mac OS X?  Using version 10.6.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ASF stands for Advanced Systems Format, it’s Microsoft's proprietary digital audio/digital video container format, especially meant for streaming media. The most common file types contained within an ASF file are Windows Media Audio (WMA) and Windows Media Video (WMV).
>
> source:
>   http://www.applemacvideo.com/howtoconvert/asf-converter-for-mac.html

On the mac, you can use MPlayer or VLC to play the file.